# How to format xml attributes, not just elements

Tags: shell, xml, xmllint

How do you format an XML document to make it easy to read element attributes?

I have a xml based webservice that returns one or two elements, but with hundreds of attributes. As I'm doing development, I sometimes need to debug this service, but it can be hard since the output is just one blob.

Consider this:

```
$ echo '<root><foo z="26" y="25" x="24" a="1" b="2" c="3" d="something more"/></root>' | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo z="26" y="25" x="24" a="1" b="2" c="3" d="something more"/>
</root>
```

I have found that tr works pretty good, but not ideal:

```
$ echo '<root><foo z="26" y="25" x="24" a="1" b="2" c="3" d="something more"/></root>' | xmllint --format - | tr ' ' \\\n
<?xml
version="1.0"?>
<root>


<foo
z="26"
y="25"
x="24"
a="1"
b="2"
c="3"
d="something
more"/>
</root>
```

Ideally the output would be something in between the xmllint and a funky hack

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo
    z="26"
    y="25"
    x="24"
    a="1"
    b="2"
    c="3"
    d="something more"/>
</root>
```

That way i can grep for things, or sort or whatever.

Comment: You are already using an XML parser, use that to query instead of trying to abuse `sed`/`grep`/`awk`. Alternatively, use `xmlstarlet` instead of `xmllint`.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth, my goal is to make a script that I could call like curl, but would format the response cleanly. That way I can do `formattedCurl.sh http://foo/service | grep prop | sort`. You're right I can use xmllint's xpath functionality, but the trick is the XML data from the service is not consistent. I tried `xmlstartlet format`, but it appears to work exactly like `xmllint -format`. Perhaps I should look into rendering the document with xslt, or perhaps a carefully crafted `sed` or `awk` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly urge away from grep/sed - they don't work for XML.

But fortunately, `perl` and [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm#xml_pp_-_xml_pretty-printer) have all sorts of magic for reformatting and extracting values as you wish. `get_xpath` works nicely for extracting a value, or you have `twig_handlers` to handle elements depending on use case. (Or just iterate using `children` or similar).

But anyway - to format your XML:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'nsgmls',
);
$twig->parse (\*DATA);
$twig->print;


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo
    z="26"
    y="25"
    x="24"
    a="1"
    b="2"
    c="3"
    d="something more"/>
</root>
```

in `nsgmls` printing, this gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root
><foo
a="1"
b="2"
c="3"
d="something more"
x="24"
y="25"
z="26"
/></root>
```

`indented_a` gives you:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo
      a="1"
      b="2"
      c="3"
      d="something more"
      x="24"
      y="25"
      z="26"
  />
</root>
```

Which seems to be pretty close to what you're seeking?

Comment: Is there a way to keep XML::Twig from alphabetizing the attributes?

Comment: Yes. When calling `new` set `keep_atts_order => 1`. But you should be wary of anything that breaks if the ordering of attributes changes, because it's _not_ parsing XML correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fantastic BeautifulSoup Python library. This code sample retrieves an XML file from a URL given as input argument to the script, parses it using LXML and then pretty prints it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import urllib2
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(sys.argv[1]), ["lxml", "xml"])
print(soup.prettify())
```

If you don't have access to LXML, you could try without `["lxml", "xml"]`, though this will parse the data als HTML rather than XML and is not the proper way.